# My current code deletes bookmarks in word, is there a way to keep the bookmarks?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a code which copies data from a spreadsheet into specific bookmarks on a particular document. When it is run it works fine, but the bookmarks are deleted from the spreadsheet. Is there a way I can keep the bookmarks in the document

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet6")

    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    objWord.Visible = True

    objWord.Documents.Open "C:\GR1 CPA Test1.docx" ' change as required

    With objWord.ActiveDocument
        .Bookmarks("CN1").Range.Text = ws.Range("C25").Value
        .Bookmarks("CN2").Range.Text = ws.Range("C25").Value
        .Bookmarks("CNo").Range.Text = ws.Range("C26").Value
        .Bookmarks("CL1").Range.Text = ws.Range("C27").Value
        .Bookmarks("Ex1").Range.Text = ws.Range("C28").Value
        .Bookmarks("Ex2").Range.Text = ws.Range("C28").Value
        .Bookmarks("Su1").Range.Text = ws.Range("C29").Value
        .Bookmarks("Su2").Range.Text = ws.Range("C29").Value
        .Bookmarks("Su3").Range.Text = ws.Range("C29").Value

    .Save
    .Close

    End With

    Set objWord = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: Cross-posted and answered at: https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/1273563-copy-data-to-word-with-cell-value-and-cell-colour.html#post5108700. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184. Also, your code *DOES NOT* delete any bookmarks.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this in the past:

```
'Replace the text in a bookmark or insert text into an empty (zero-length) bookmark
Sub SetBookmarkText(oDoc As Word.Document, sBookmark As String, sText As String)

    Dim BMRange As Word.Range

    If oDoc.Range.Bookmarks.Exists(sBookmark) Then
      Set BMRange = oDoc.Range.Bookmarks(sBookmark).Range
      BMRange.Text = sText
      oDoc.Range.Bookmarks.Add sBookmark, BMRange
    Else
      MsgBox "Bookmark '" & sBookmark & "' not found in document '" & oDoc.Name & "'" & _
              vbCrLf & "Content not updated"
    End If

End Sub
```

Usage:

```
    Dim ws As Worksheet, doc as object

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet6")

    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    objWord.Visible = True

    Set doc = objWord.Documents.Open("C:\GR1 CPA Test1.docx")

    SetBookmarkText doc, "CN1", ws.Range("C25").Value
    SetBookmarkText doc, "CN2", ws.Range("C25").Value
    'etc etc

    doc.Save
    doc.Close
    Set objWord = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. My current code is assigned to a Command Button, so could I do the same with the code you have posted above?